# I want to override the api method for /spree_oauth/token in spree 4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm using the Spree storefront API for e-commerce.

```
/spree_oauth/token
```

The above routes only generate access-tokens by getting the email & password. I want to override the method I couldn't find in the repo. I want to add some extra validation of my own with email and password to generate an access token.

I did find the route it's on index.yml but still not sure how to override it from there as I am new to rails.